# Laravel blade view page is empty even though there is source code

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

My blade view shows a empty page, but if I press CTRL + U to show the source code, then I get this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://localhost/portal_testing/public/css/style.css'/>
    <script src='http://localhost/portal_testing/public/js/main.js'/>
</head>
<body>
    <div>   
        <div class='infoBox'>
            <h4 class='infoBoxTitle'>Log:</h4>
            <div class='infoBoxContent'> 
               <p>test</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='errorBox'>
            <h4 class='errorBoxTitle'>Error Log:</h4>
            <div class='errorBoxContent'> 
               <p>test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why is it not rendering even though there is valid code?

UPDATE:

---

Javascript:

```
//Accordion:
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
```

---

CSS

```
.infoBox {
    font-family: arial;
    padding:2px;
    background-color: #DADADA;
    min-width: 300px;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin:2px;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.infoBoxTitle {
    padding:4px;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: red;
    margin: 1px;
    text-decoration: underline;

}

.infoBoxContent {
    font-size: 10px;
    padding-left:5px;
    margin-left:10px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

.errorBox {
    font-family: arial;
    padding:2px;
    background-color: #838383;
    min-width: 300px;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin:2px;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.errorBoxTitle {
    padding:4px;
    font-family: calibry;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: white;
    margin: 1px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.errorBoxContent {
    color: white;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding-left:5px;
    margin-left:10px;
    border: 4px solid white;
}
```

Comment: Make sure that there is no fatal error and content is not getging hidden using some CSS

Comment: Please show the contents of your CSS and JS files, they could be responsible for hiding the elements.

Comment: How do I know if there is a fatal error? By viewing the apache log?

Comment: yes, apache error log

Comment: Also make sure to check your browser's developer console for any javascript errors.

Comment: Comment out that javascript code and see if its working then or not

Comment: It works after I commented out the javascript! But why? There are no javascript errors. It makes no sense to me.

Comment: Assuming no server errors and so on, where is the element with class `accordion` you trying to access in JS.. 
is this the full html the browser receives ?

Comment: The accordion element does not even exist jet, I included the script because I plan to build an accordion later.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem...
I noticed that all the content was rendered inside of the script tag:

[image: inspect html]

The reason is, becaues the script element was missing it's closing tag.

---

**Fix:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='{{ URL::asset("js/main.js") }}'></script>
```